# Drupal 8.5 from admin/content "ADD CONTENT" button is missing.

Tags: drupal

I am using theme "Seven". I am not sure why caused this issue. Suddenly I do not see my "Add Content" button on admin/content page anymore. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It can be permissions issue. Are you using master admin account or some other?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have resolved it. It was one of my custom module that was causing this issue.